# Is special memory needed for MacBooks? 

Tags: memory, macbook

I've read some conflicting articles on Macbooks and memory upgrades.  Some say you have to buy the "special" Mac memory, others say manufacturers like Partriot and Ocz will work fine.

My Macbook (non-pro) is about 6 months old with it's 2 GB of memory (SO-DIMM 1066MHz DDR3).

Do I require special RAM, or will any work?

Answer (score 3):

Anecdata: 1 iMac, 1 Macbook, both upgraded with aftermarket RAM, both just, y'know, worked. (Both are older than yours by a few years, but I have no reason to think that should be significant.)

From [crucial.com](http://www.crucial.com/mac/index.aspx), in my case, largely because their Memory Advisor Tool makes it simple to order the right parts.

Comment: Same anecdata here. Crucial RAM has worked well for my DDR3 needs lately (Macbook alum. Fall 2009). Kingston ValueRAM has worked for DDR2 before (Macbook white Early 2008).